# ApproximateTime not working with nodelets

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, message-filters, nodelet, approximatetime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a nodelet that publishes a few topics and another nodelet that subscribes the topics and republishes a custom topic with all the synchronized messages.

If I start the two nodelets in two separate nodelet managers everything works as expected, if I use a single nodelet manager that loads both the nodelets the subscriber receives only a few messages than stops.

I'm using the ApproximateTime policy.

The topics run at different frequencies: 400Hz, 15Hz and 50Hz.

Any idea about the cause of the problem and about how to debug to find a possible cause?

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346690/approximatetime-not-working-with-nodelets/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2020-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-16**:
Please do not close questions when you've actually anwered them.

Just click the checkmark to the left of the answer. That will provide a much clearer indication the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution to the problem.

I was wrongly not creating a new message before each publishing.

In my particular case I had an IMU message to be synchronized with camera images and I was creating the message once in the `OnInit` function.
Instead we must create each single shared pointer message just before publishing it: `sensor_msgs::ImuPtr imuMsg(new sensor_msgs::Imu);`

---

Originally posted by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) with karma: 541 on 2020-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0